# Abrir modal al dar Tab en una Row de Datagrid

Tags: wpf, material-design

Tengo un DataGrid que se llena con los datos seleccionados en otra Grid, pero para abrirla tengo un boton, me piden que al apretar TAB en la primer Row del Grid, el modal con el segundo grid se abra, sin necesidad de darle al boton que abre el mismo modal, he intentado con el evento KeyDown pero nada que me funciona, alguna idea de porque?

[image: Grid desde la cual se debe permitir abrir el modal con TAB]

[image: Modal que debe abrir al apretar TAB]

```
private void GridArticulos_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
                var grid = (DataGrid)sender;
                if (Key.Tab == e.Key)
                {
                    foreach (var row in grid.SelectedItems)
                    {
                    DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand.Execute(ArticulosModal, null);
                    }
                }

        }
```

Comment: Muestra el codigo. Nada me funciona no es algo que sirva como para saber que es lo que pasa...

Comment: Listo, ya lo corregi

Comment: Y si utilizas el evento `OnBlur` mejor ?

Comment: Ese codigo llega a la linea que abre el DialogHost?

Comment: Ese metodo lo llamo en el xaml en la propiedad del datagrid KeyDown="GridArticulos_KeyDown", pero no me funca